# Behaviour of last-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Why is the last `p` not highlighted?

w3schools says:

> *Specify a background color for the p element that is the last child of its parent*

So the last `p` should be highlighted right?

```
<style> 
div p:last-child {
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>

<div>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
  <span>The first span.</span>
<div>
```

for you saying, use this - that is not my question:

```
div p:last-of-type {...}
```

Comment: last-child doesn't care about the type, w3schools information is unreliable, turn to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) instead

Comment: try to avoid the use of w3schools

Comment: :last-child is very similar to :last-of-type but with one critical difference: it is less specific. :last-child will only try to match the very last child of a parent element, while last-of-type will match the last occurrence of a specified element, even if it doesn't come dead last in the HTML. - http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-child/

Comment: [Here is a very good extension for Chrome.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/w3schools-hider/igiahejkpbnbnekdaefddmdceocmjpll) It removes all w3school results from Google. Much easier to get quality resources this way!

Comment: @Kitler Yes, don't rely on w3schools, but in this case, there is nothing wrong with their description.

Comment: Simple misreading of the docs. *Specify a background color for the `p` element that is the last child of its parent*. **So the last `p` should be highlighted right?** No, because there **is** no `p` element that is the last child of its parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's worth mentioning that W3Schools is an external resource. It isn't the official CSS documentation. The `:last-child` pseudo-class is defined in the CSS Selectors specification here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo. This specification states:

> The `:last-child` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last child of some other element.

`:last-child` selects specifically *the* last child. Here `p:last-child` would apply styling to a `p` element *only* if it is the last child. In your case, `span` is the last child, not `p`, therefore there's nothing for your selector to select.

#### Example 1

```
<div>
  <p>Foo.</p>
  <span>Bar.</span>
<div>
```

Here `span` is the last child, not `p`. `p:last-child` would not select anything.

#### Example 2

```
<div>
  <p>Foo.</p>
  <span>Bar.</span>
  <p>Baz.</p>
<div>
```

Here `p` *is* the last child, so `p:last-child` would select the last `p` element (whose text here is "Baz.".

This behaviour is exactly why the `:last-of-type` selector exists. `:first-child` and `:last-child` will always only look select the first or last child.

Answer (score 12):

**[`Last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo)** is not selecting what you're expecting it to select (You need **[`last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo)**, instead). The `last-child` property only applies to elements that are the last child element of their parent container. In your case, `span` is the `last-child`:

```html
<div>
    <p>The first paragraph.</p>
    <p>The second paragraph.</p>
    <p>The third paragraph.</p>
    <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
    <span>The first span.</span> <!-- this <span> is the "last-child" -->
<div>
```

So the CSS selector `p:last-child {}` doesn't have anything to select, because it's looking for the last child of a container **that is also a** `<p>` **element**. Here is a more concrete, real-world analogy:

You have three children:

- Jack, aged 17
- Susan, aged 14
- Alex, aged 10

In markup, this looks like:

```html
<mother>
    <jack>17</jack>
    <susan>14</susan>
    <alex>10</alex>
</mother>
```

A blank `:last-child {}` selector will select Alex, because he's the *last child* you had. However, you are trying to select the last child of a certain type, in this case we'll say their `name` is the type. `Susan:last-child`, then, won't work, because even though Susan is the last of your children *to be named Susan* (e.g. to have type `name` of "Susan"), she's *not* the last child you've had.

If you use `last-of-type` instead, it will work, because the fourth `p` is the `last-of-type` `p`.